# Importing remote PowerShell commands into a friendly named module

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, pssnapin

I've managed to use [`Import-PSSession`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849970.aspx) to create proxies to PowerShell commands (Modules, SnapIns, etc). It seems to work fine, but the syntax to avoid name collisions doesn't feel very natural.

I have a 3rd party PowerShell SnapIn containing the cmdlet `Do-Stuff`. The SnapIn is installed locally, and also on remote computers `A` and `B`.

Is it possible to somehow import these SnapIns as (nicely named) modules so that I can call `Do-Stuff` locally or on `A` or `B`?

What I currently have using Prefixes:

```
   Do-Stuff                     #Locally
   Do-OnAStuff                  #Invoke on A
   Do-OnBStuff                  #Invoke on B
```

Or, allowing clobbering to avoid the unnatural (in my opinion) cmdlet renaming:

```
   SnapinName\Do-Stuff          #Invoke locally. Local SnapIn clobbered
   tmp_h0jcyaaq.p4f\Do-Stuff    #Invoke on A. Can I control module name?
   tmp_rbk2rv5y.lbb\Do-Stuff    #Invoke on B.
```

What I'd like to do:

```
   Do-Stuff                     #Invoke locally
   OnA\Do-Stuff                 #Invoke on machine A
   OnB\Do-Stuff                 #Invoke on machine B
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the -Prefix only modifies the -Noun of your Verb-Noun cmdlet.